# Detect App Getting Focus in React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to detect when the app gains the focus back (i.e. switch to it from another app) in order to perform a certain task. Is there a way to detect this in React Native?

What I'm doing is copying a file to a temp location, opening it with an external viewer, and then I want to delete the file when the user switches back from the app.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `AppState` module might be what you are looking for. Have a look at the [documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/appstate).

Comment: This answer seems incomplete. Which event name?

Comment: The 'change' event is the one that I would recommend.

Answer (score 0):

This functionality can be solved with the help of **AppState API**'s addEventListener method.
**Kindly note**, if you are using react-native 0.65 and above, this [**documentation**](https://reactnative.dev/docs/appstate) will be OK.

###### But, if you are using react-native 0.64 and below, its better to use your version specific documentation because there is a change in the way the **"remove()"** method(unsubscribe logic) is used for the event listener. This is the documentation for [**0.64**](https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.64/appstate) and the older use of the remove method.